# Update the counter by +1 when another record with two similar values exists in xslt 2.0

Tags: counter, xslt-2.0, increment

I have the below xml:

```
<EmployeeLeaveDataUpsertRequest>
<Row>
    <Emp_id>11</Emp_id>
    <Pay_slip_no>1</Pay_slip_no>
    <Pay_comp>AU_0299</Pay_comp>
    <Hours>136</Hours>
    <Date_from_ec>20170401</Date_from_ec>
    <Date_to_ec>20170429</Date_to_ec>
    <Date_ped> </Date_ped>
    <No_of_period>1</No_of_period>
    <Ma_ind>M</Ma_ind>
    <Fa_ind>N</Fa_ind>
    <Counter>1</Counter>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Emp_id>12</Emp_id>
    <Pay_slip_no>1</Pay_slip_no>
    <Pay_comp>AU_0900</Pay_comp>
    <Hours>40</Hours>
    <Date_from_ec>20170206</Date_from_ec>
    <Date_to_ec>20170210</Date_to_ec>
    <Date_ped> </Date_ped>
    <No_of_period>1</No_of_period>
    <Ma_ind>M</Ma_ind>
    <Fa_ind>N</Fa_ind>
    <Counter>1</Counter>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Emp_id>11</Emp_id>
    <Pay_slip_no>1</Pay_slip_no>
    <Pay_comp>AU_0299</Pay_comp>
    <Hours>8</Hours>
    <Date_from_ec>20170111</Date_from_ec>
    <Date_to_ec>20170115</Date_to_ec>
    <Date_ped> </Date_ped>
    <No_of_period>1</No_of_period>
    <Ma_ind>M</Ma_ind>
    <Fa_ind>N</Fa_ind>
    <Counter>1</Counter>
</Row>
```

In the above xml you can see that every record has an element counter with default value set as 1.

In an event for same Emp_id and Pay_comp then I need to set the counter as 1 for first record , 2 for second record and so on.

Like in the above xml you can see two records where the Emp_id is 11 and Pay_comp is AU_0299 -- so for the first one set the counter as 1 and for the next one a 2.

output xml:

```
<EmployeeLeaveDataUpsertRequest>
<Row>
    <Emp_id>11</Emp_id>
    <Pay_slip_no>1</Pay_slip_no>
    <Pay_comp>AU_0299</Pay_comp>
    <Hours>136</Hours>
    <Date_from_ec>20170401</Date_from_ec>
    <Date_to_ec>20170429</Date_to_ec>
    <Date_ped> </Date_ped>
    <No_of_period>1</No_of_period>
    <Ma_ind>M</Ma_ind>
    <Fa_ind>N</Fa_ind>
    <Counter>1</Counter>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Emp_id>11</Emp_id>
    <Pay_slip_no>1</Pay_slip_no>
    <Pay_comp>AU_0299</Pay_comp>
    <Hours>8</Hours>
    <Date_from_ec>20170111</Date_from_ec>
    <Date_to_ec>20170115</Date_to_ec>
    <Date_ped> </Date_ped>
    <No_of_period>1</No_of_period>
    <Ma_ind>M</Ma_ind>
    <Fa_ind>N</Fa_ind>
    <Counter>2</Counter>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Emp_id>12</Emp_id>
    <Pay_slip_no>1</Pay_slip_no>
    <Pay_comp>AU_0900</Pay_comp>
    <Hours>40</Hours>
    <Date_from_ec>20170206</Date_from_ec>
    <Date_to_ec>20170210</Date_to_ec>
    <Date_ped> </Date_ped>
    <No_of_period>1</No_of_period>
    <Ma_ind>M</Ma_ind>
    <Fa_ind>N</Fa_ind>
    <Counter>1</Counter>
</Row>
```

I have tried for loop but couldn't succeed. Need your inputs on the XSLT code which could achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a key to identify duplicates, with XSLT 3.0 (as now supported by Saxon 9.8 or current versions of Altova XMLSpy and Raptor) it is as easy as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:key name="group" match="Row" use="Emp_id , Pay_comp" composite="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="Row[not(. is key('group', (Emp_id , Pay_comp))[1])]/Counter">
        <xsl:copy>{index-of(key('group', (../Emp_id , ../Pay_comp)), ..)}</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 2.0 you can translate the above to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="group" match="Row" use="concat(Emp_id, '|', Pay_comp)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row[not(. is key('group', concat(Emp_id, '|', Pay_comp))[1])]/Counter">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="index-of(key('group', concat(../Emp_id, '|', ../Pay_comp)), ..)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, for some cases the out put is like 4 5, and 3 4. Where it should be only a single digit output.

Comment: @Vicky, I think I made a mistake there using `index-of` in that context, it should be e.g. `http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_index-of-node.html` that is `functx:index-of-node(key('group', (../Emp_id , ../Pay_comp)), ..)` with the linked to function included or inserted into the stylesheet.